# Center button based on media query

Tags: html, css, mobile

I'm trying to create a button which will be left aligned on desktop, but center aligned on Mobile. Somehow the only changes I see when I use the code below is that the button is adjusting it's size to the screen, but it's not getting centered. What am I doing wrong?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
  body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

table {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  background: red;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .centeredButton {
    text-align: center;
  }
}
</style>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <table >
      <tbody>
        <tr>
  <td class="innertd buttonblock centeredButton" bgcolor="#FFA617" style=" padding: 0px; border-radius: 99px; -moz-border-radius: 99px; -webkit-border-radius: 99px; background-color: #FFA617;">
   <a style=" font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #540021 !important; text-align: center; display: block; text-decoration: none; font-weight: bold; padding: 7px 14px; background-color: #FFA617; border: 10px solid #FFA617; border-radius: 99px; -moz-border-radius: 99px; -webkit-border-radius: 99px;"
    target="_blank" class="buttonstyles" href=""
    title="" alias="" conversion="true" data-linkto="https://">Stap
    nu over
   </a>
  </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    <script src="src/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Displaying `block` without setting a `width` will display as wide as parent is.
Try setting `width: 200px` on your `<a>`

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you're button is inside a table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue with your table CSS, as its having only 50% width its not allowing you to move or centered align.

Put below table CSS in media code, it will help you out.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
   table {
    margin : 0 auto;
   }

  .centeredButton {
    text-align: center;
   }
}
```